# Getting Twitter's context_annotation from a string of text

Tags: twitter

I want to get twitter’s context annotations for a string of text data, say "I like coding"

The long way to do this would be to post the text as a tweet, after which twitter would generate the context_annotations for the tweet.

But is there any other way I can get the context_annotations for a string of text without it being a tweet?

My main goal is to receive a string from a user and return tweets resembling that string. I am planning to find the tweets by doing a context_search using the Twitter API. In order to do that I would obviously first need to get the context_annotations (with the domain & entity Ids) from the string.

I found this link in Twitter's official API documentation that helps extract context annotations. It seems broken. Furthermore, it doesn't take text; it takes in the URL of the tweet.

https://tweet-entity-extractor.glitch.me/